# How to see all TODO tasks in Android Studio?

Tags: android, android-studio

How could I open a view in Android Studio where all tasks that I've created using `// TODO` comments would be displayed?

Comment: How to remove all the //TODO

Answer (score 181, accepted):

You can find this "view" on bottom left menu bar.
Called TODO

[image: TODO]

(or)

**Android Studio**

go to View -> Tool Windows -> TODO to display the TODO panel

Anything marked

// TODO

should be visible in the list panel

[image]

Comment: what if I cannot see this view?

Comment: Maybe try menu Window->Restore Default Layout (Maj+F12)

Comment: if you can see it View->Tool Windows->TODO

Answer (score 17):

Also, you can press the ***Shift twice*** and write **TODO** in the  search bar to display the **TODO panel**.